# Manual Sizing for a JQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-accordion

I am presently building a rather interesting UI, such that a JQuery Accordion is within a JQuery Dialog.  What has me stumped is defining a specific height for this Accordion.  I have attempted to use `{fillSpace: true}`, but this causes the accordion to grow past the edge of the dialog (which I have configured as **not** resizable).  Hence, fillSpace and automatic height adjustment is not what I want.  Instead, I would like to be able to set a specific size for the Accordion (preferably by number of pixels).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add spacing within the accordion sections so that Auto-Hide appropriately accommodates its contents.  Spacing could be `<br/>` tags, divs or other cosmetic elements.  Then ensure that the accordion auto-height is enabled.

Note: this is how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Post what you have tried to jsbin or jsfiddle.
In my solutions containing accordions I usually place the according to a div with appropriate header and content panels; this div should be able to grow.I uses percentages for sizing.

Comment: There are a lot of JavaScript dependencies and some additional complexity that makes it difficult for me to share a complete example of my code.  What I can say is my Div structure is as follows:  Div M { Div C { Div L { Accordion Div } Div R }}}.  Given this, how do I define the height of the Accordion to a specific size?